# Google removed over 100.000 Indexes… But why?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I am the owner of a synonym page. The Problem i am currently facing is that Google Search Console is automatically removing my pages.

My Index Count in 20th April
[image: aprilIndex]

My Index Count in 20th May
[image: mayIndex]

Google decided to remove over 100.000 Indexes in only 1 month!

I am neither saying Google that it should remove my Pages nor did something illegal (as far as I know)

I just wanted to note that my site doesnt exist that long.